# ow can I fetch the value from mongdb doctrine using id and condition 'enabled'

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have a collection of users and need to retrieve the users using id and condition enabled=1

my code

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
$users = $dm->getRepository('xxxxBundle:User')->find($id);
```

how it possible like

```
$users = $dm->getRepository('xxxxBundle:User')->find($id,enabled=1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will return collection

```
$users = $dm->getRepository('xxxxBundle:User')->findBy(array('id' => $id, 'enabled' => 1));
```

or

```
$user = $dm->getRepository('xxxxBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id, 'enabled' => 1));
```

to get single user entity